# I cannot connect socket client to socket server on different WiFi networks

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket, serversocket

I am learning about socket programming with Android.  I have two mobile devices.  Both are connected to different WiFi networks.  My server app is running on one device and client app is running on another devices.  I cannot connect the client to server with different WiFi network.  Why?
Please help me and sorry for my poor communication.

Client code:

```
class ClientSideThread extends Thread {

    String response;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.111",8085);

            OutputStream outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            out.writeUTF("hi");
            InputStream inFromServer = socket.getInputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

            response = in.readUTF();

            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();                

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                sIpAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
                sPort = socket.getPort();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                message = sb.toString();
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                printWriter.println(message);
                printWriter.flush();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String sDisplayMsg = "Replay:" + message;
                        TextView rowTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        rowTextView.setText(sDisplayMsg);
                        linearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checked whether the server is listening in the port, your client is sending a request to connect?

Comment: yes i checked and i am getting Socket Timeout exception in client code

Comment: That can occur when the client side is unable to write the output stream. Hardcode the port number 8085 instead of socketServerPORT in server side.

Comment: yes i tried but i am getting same error

Comment: What do you mean different WiFi network? Different LAN or different APs?

Comment: means different router

Comment: @Siddharthan are those routers on the same LAN network?

Comment: No both are different LAN network

Answer (score 0):

You mention that they are on two different WiFi networks. My doubt is that the two networks are not connected.

Even before you try with Andriod, please check if the Server Device IP address is reachable from the client network. You can connect a laptop or a desktop to the client network and issue a ping command `ping 192.168.1.111` to see if the target IP is reachable or not. If it is reachable, do a `telnet 192.168.1.111 8085`. If the telnet does not connect and the ping is reachable, then it mans the Server Socket is not bound to the port 8085. If the ping itself is not reachable, then the 2 routers are probably not interlinked. There is a possibility that ping is disabled on the server device. You can issue a `tracert 192.168.1.111` to see how far the network packets go. Look for the gateway IP of the target server. If that is not found, the 2 routers are probably not linked and you will need to link them.

Comment: thanks for replay.i tried but i cannot  reachable  server ip address.i am getting this error.why?Pinging 192.168.1.118 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.118:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: As I guessed, the 2 networks are not connected to each other. Just to confirm, please try `tracert` and `teltnet`. If both the WiFi routers are under your control and in the same location, you could connect the two with physical network cable and configure them to forward packets from one to another. You will need help of someone who understands networking to do this.  
Your code looks OK from a quick check.

Comment: From an architectural standpoint in most applications, I would expect the server to be an independent application running on a server with a static IP that is accessible over the internet so that any device can access it. You might be better off writing a standalone java application for the server. Your code wont change much from the Android code you have written.